# laravel error Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar::register(): Failed

Tags: laravel

Hi I have a problem in laravel version 7
When i run Laravel in localhost, every thing is OK but when i run in Cpanel i get this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
> Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar::register(): Failed opening required '????/laravelPortal/routes/Api.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear')

To make sure the files are loaded so i tested other Laravel sample in this location and it was true work also i remove all of routes file but i get Same above Error

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {
  Route::post('login', 'Api\UserController@login');
  Route::post('register', 'Api\UserController@register');
  Route::get('getUser/{id}', 'Api\UserController@getUser')->middleware(['auth:api','scopes:admin,user']);
  Route::get('getUser', 'Api\UserController@getUser');
  Route::get('logout', 'Api\UserController@logout') ->middleware(['auth:api','scope:admin,user']);
  Route::get('checkAdmin', 'Api\UserController@checkAdmin')->middleware(['auth:api','scope:admin']);
 });
```

my composer :

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/passport": "7.5.1",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "morilog/jalali": "3.*",
    "shetabit/payment": "^2.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Do the file `routes/Api.php` exists and is readable? Remember that in linux systems the filenames are case sensitive.

Comment: this file is exists but how check this file readable or no? i dont have access linux server and other sample laravel is work

Comment: Check chmod for file. Probably you can do it uding ftp.

Comment: i dont think this solution is true because other source laravel work in this route host

Comment: "Failed opening required '????/laravelPortal/routes/Api.php'" this means just two things: 1. The file doesn't exists 2. PHP has no permission to read it. Other projects might work because they was uploaded with correct file permissions.

Comment: I use cpanel and I see this file in routes folder also this file permission is 0644! i dont access to linux server for run chmod

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue with linux,it was a kind of case sensitive issue from my end,
i corrected the filename and file and that solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Route::prefix('user')->group(function () {Your routes here});